# get response error from rest api using angular2

Tags: angular, rest, error-handling, response

Client.service.ts:

```
add(client: Client): Observable<Client> {
    return this.authHttp.post(this.URI, client)
      .map((res) => res.json()
      //...errors if any
      ,(message)=>message.json());
```

Client.add.componement.ts:

```
  this.clientService.add(client)
    .subscribe(_client => {
      this.onAdd.emit(_client);
    },
      message => console.log("THIS ERROR"+message));
```

But the result in case of error is :[the result is always bad request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1zL0.png)

How can i get the message or the list of errors [the result i get in brower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4eMs.png)

Comment: In the subscribe function, the second parameter is error callback function. You can use it.

Comment: when i change th function like this:
 this.clientService.add(client)
        .subscribe(_client => {        },
          error => console.log("THIS ERROR"+error));
i get the same error and my problem is that i cannot get the response details in case of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using [angular2-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-jwt) as `authHttp` make sure you import it and inject correctly in service:

`import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';` ->
`constructor (private authHttp: AuthHttp) { }`

Then, you can do something like (make sure to add content-type/request options to POST requests):

```
add(client: Client): Observable<Client> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // set content-type
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // create a request option

    return this.authHttp.post(this.URI, client, options)
        .map((res) => res.json())
        //...errors if any
        .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
}

private handleErrorObservable(error: Response | any) {
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
}
```

Then when you call it:

```
this._clientService.add(client)
    .subscribe(
         res => console.log(res),
         err => console.log(err)
     );
```

Otherwise make sure you are returning your desired responses in JSON format in your web api code.

Comment: thank you , i tried it before but i got this error : ERROR TypeError: this.authHttp.post(...).map(...).catch is not a function

Comment: @babbina_sou If you are using [authHttp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-jwt) are you importing and injecting it correctly into the constructor?